# Ubuntu 14.04: Wifi disabled after suspend

Tags: 14.04, wireless, suspend, hp, hp-pavilion

I recently bought a new HP pavilion 15 (has windows 8) and installed (dual boot) a fresh version of ubuntu 14.04 (64bit).

After installation, the built-in wifi wasn't working so i used a usb wifi stick to connect to Internet. Few minutes later, i tried the built-in wifi and it started working fine.

However i noticed that it gets disabled after i suspend and re-relogin. The wifi switch gets greyed and can't click it anymore and i see the message "wifi is disabled by hardware switch), although there's no hardware switch in this HP.

The only solution to get the wifi back is by restart (and that's really annoying).

I spent days trying solutions that i found for similar problems in this forum and other websites but with no luck.

The `sudo rfkill list all` displays the following:

```
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

The unblock command doesn't change anything.

(wifi works well on windows)

Please help me find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Hi, Do you have the solution for this? I'm also affected by this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on;
esac
```

Put this in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi` and the problem should be fixed immediately.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: in my case, nm was just disabling wifi on resume ( 14.04) . it worked  after fixing command  to nmcli nm wifi on; ( command "r" didn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

Type the following commands in terminal

```
sudo rmmod -f rt2500usb<br>
sudo rfkill unblock all<br>
sudo modprobe rt2500us<br>
rfkill list all
```

If this doesn't work, then type in terminal

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But you have to do the second method every time your wireless is being diabled

Comment: it didn't work too

Comment: I hope you  have tried the second method in my answer(sudo service network-manager restart) which should mostly work. If that too doesn't work, then try sudo service networking restart

Comment: I did. it just restarts the network, but wifi remains disabled.

Comment: What is the output of rfkill list

Comment: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes